# Modify Wordpress email text with functiion

Tags: wordpress, function, email, contact-form, contact-form-7

I want to get, modify and return the message of the sending emails in WordPress with a function.

I tried with gettext filter with no results. I tried wp_mail filter where I feel is a better approach but I can not get this to work.

```
add_filter('wp_mail','edit_email', 10,1);
function edit_email(){
    $args['message']=str_replace( 'foo', 'bar', $args['message'] );
    return $args['message'];
}
```

Comment: Correct your code brother ->  $args['message']=str_replace( 'foo', 'bar', $args['message'] );

Comment: You are absolutely right. However this does not change the message of the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this filter function, return `$args` instead of just `$args['message']`:

```
add_filter('wp_mail','edit_email', 10,1);
function edit_email($args){
    $args['message'] = str_replace( 'foo', 'bar', $args['message'] );
    return $args;
}
```

Edit: added $args as a function argument.

Comment: Now I just get an error while I press submit to the contact form frontend (Fail. Try again...).

Comment: That's because I copied your code verbatim and just adapted the `return`. Your function was missing the argument to the `wp_mail` filter function in the first place. Now it should work